# React + Typescript: setTimeout in For Loop is not populating array consecutively, or at all

Tags: reactjs, typescript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm building a function that makes images of random cars animate across the screen, and I want to stagger the population of the "carsLeft" array with a setTimeout..(which I will ultimately randomize the delay time).

everything works until I try to use a setTimeout. With the code below, no cars get are shown. a Console.log shows that the "carsLeft" array does not populate. When I remove the setTimeout all the cars are shown (at once of course). I have tried IIDE still no luck. Been stuck on this one for awhile, Please Help!

```
function Traffic() {
  let carsLeft: any = [];
  const generateCarLeft = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        carsLeft.push(
          <CarLeft key={i} className="car__left">
            <img
              src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
              alt=""
            />
          </CarLeft>
        );
      }, 3000);
    }
  };

  generateCarLeft();
  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsLeft}</div>;
}

export default Traffic;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate elements through the loop and happen after the component is mounted is using `React.useEffect` hook, for example

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  generateCarsLeft()
}, [])
```

and also using the `carsLeft` as a state will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If do without state and setTimeout it'll work because before first render(mount) all the data is available.

but if you use on first render list is empty and after setTimeout it'll update variable but react does not know that variable is updated you have to use the state to solve this issue.

```
function Traffic() {
  const [carsLeft, setCarsLeft] = useState([]);
  const generateCarLeft = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCarsLeft((items) => [
          ...items,
          <CarLeft key={i} className="car__left">
            <img
              src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
              alt=""
            />
          </CarLeft>,
        ]);
      }, 3000);
    }
  };

  generateCarLeft();
  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsLeft}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Because `for` is synchronous, this would do nothing for 3s, and then add 5 cars all at once.

Answer (score 0):

1. A React component is essentially just a function, so if you declare a variable inside that function it will be re-created each time you call it. If you want any value to persist between calls it has to be saved somewhere else. In React that 'somewhere' is state.
2. Unless React detects changes to the state it won't even re-render the component.

So as of now your component is called once, 3 seconds later all 5 new elements are added to the array at once, but the component is no re-rendered, because React is not tracking this change. I'll give you an example of how you make it work, but I'd suggest you learn more about React's concepts of state and life cycle.

```
function Traffic() {
 [carsLeft, setCarsLeft] = React.useState([]);

 React.useEffect(()=>{
  if(carsLeft.length > 4) return;
   setTimeout(() => {
     setCarsLeft( cl => [...cl,  
      <CarLeft key={i} className="car__left">
        <img
          src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
          alt=""/>]
      );
     }, 3000);

   })
  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsLeft}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out, I had to use IIFE in conjunction with State. posting answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this did run, it would not run the way you want it to. Because the `for` loop is extremely fast, you would wait 3s to get 5 cars at once.

You need to get rid of the loop. And you need to wrap all side effects in a `useEffect` hook, and all persistent variables like `carsLeft` in a `useState` hook.

```js
export default function Traffic() {
  const [carsLeft, setCarsLeft] = useState<Array<ReactNode>>([]);
  const timeout = useRef<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if (carsLeft.length < 5)
        setCarsLeft([
          ...carsLeft,
          <CarLeft key={carsLeft.length} className="car__left">
            <img
              src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
              alt=""
            />
          </CarLeft>
        ]);
      else clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    };
  }, [carsLeft]);

  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsLeft}</div>;
}
```

Codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-driscoll-6k6u8?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I like this solution, thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
const list = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you"];
function App() {
  const [myList, updateList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        updateList((prvList) => ([...prvList, list[i]]));
      }, 1000 * i) // * i is important
    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        myList.map(li => (<div key={li}>{li}</div>))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved all the issues and everything works perfectly. I used @Summer 's approach to remove the for loop and let the useEffect + State changes create its own endless loop. Instead of a setTimeout I used a setInterval method. An issue I had with Summer's solution was using "carsOnTheLeft.length" to generate key values. This caused multiple keys to have the same value and resulted with some issues. To fix this I created a new piece of state "carLeftIndex" to generate a unique key on every re-render. The generated objects are removed from the state array when the animation is complete thanks to React's "onAnimationEnd()' which triggers the "handleRemoveItem" function. **Heres my working code, thank you for your answers!**

```
const getRandomNumber = (min: number, max: number) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const carListDay = [car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4, car_5, car_6];

function Traffic() {
  const [carsOnTheLeft, setCarsOnTheLeft] = useState<any>([]);
  const timeout = useRef<any>();
  const [carLeftIndex, setCarLeftIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRandomNumberToString = (min: number, max: number) => {
      const result = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      return result.toString();
    };
    setCarLeftIndex(carLeftIndex + 1);

    const CarLeft = styled.div`
      animation-duration: ${getRandomNumberToString(3, 10)}s;
    `;

    timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
      getRandomNumberToString(2, 9);
  if (carsOnTheLeft.length < 15)
        setCarsOnTheLeft([
          ...carsOnTheLeft,
          <CarLeft
            key={carLeftIndex}
            className="car__left"
            onAnimationEnd={(e) => handleRemoveItem(e)}
          >
            <img
              src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
              alt=""
            />
          </CarLeft>,
        ]);
 else clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }, getRandomNumber(100, 5000));
    console.log(carsOnTheLeft);
    console.log(carLeftIndex);
    const handleRemoveItem = (e: any) => {
      setCarsOnTheLeft((carsOnTheLeft: any) =>
        carsOnTheLeft.filter((key: any, i: any) => i !== 0)
      );
    };

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    };
  }, [carsOnTheLeft]);

  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsOnTheLeft}</div>;
```